# How can I write xml attribute with +sign?

Tags: xml, lxml

I need a xml file with :

```
<xml>
    <per+1>value1</per+2>
    <per+2>value2</per2>
</xml>
```

I am using python lxml for creation of xml tree. I parsed the string to xml using bs4. But the result is

```
<per>+1&gt;value1</per>
<per>+2&gt;value2</per>
```

I tried using + , no result.

Comment: Why do you want to use an XML library to generate something that isn't XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot use a `+` in XML attribute (or element) names.**

First of all, in XML terminology, you're asking about ***element*** names; ***attributes*** are different:

```
<elementName attributeName="attributeValue"/>
```

Regardless, though, both element and attribute names must follow the [W3C XML BNF for component names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ```
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> ```

The `+` character is not included.  Your only options are those characters that are listed.   Perhaps use a `_` character or some string such as `Plus` or forgo trying to communicate the `+` concept in the name and use an attribute or a character in the element string value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. XML does not support `+` characters in tag or attribute names.

Comment: What is the solution then? using <per value="+1">value1<per>?